# Is it possible to retrieve a post and its metadata at the same time?

Tags: post-meta, get-posts

I usually use two steps to retreive a list of posts and the associated metadata:  call get_posts(or a custom WP_Query), and then loop through each post returned and retrieve each posts metadata one by one.

Is there any way to combine this into a single query?  I guess I'm looking for something like a get_posts_with_meta() function?

Comment: Please clarify. Single SQL query? That would probably be convoluted and not very practical. Single PHP function? That would be trivial to write, but what difference would it make in practice?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *accomplish*? Without some context, it is difficult to understand the purpose/need for what you're asking.

Comment: @ChipBennett He wants to return posts within the loop along with all of the associated post_meta (i.e. Meta Key/Meta Values) without necessarily having to define the key/value within the query or know what the keys/values are.

Comment: @userabuser but you're basically restating his question. I'm trying to understand **why** the OP wants to do this.

Comment: You opened your question with "What.." and not "Why.."

Comment: I was looking for a single query to return both the posts and it's associated metadata at the same time.  AFter researching a little more, it seems that not only would this be convoluted, but also work against most of WP's caching solutions, so I'm just going to keep it two separate steps.

Comment: @ChipBennett I had some custom post types that basically only had a single piece of metadata that i needed ( a json object).  I was thinking, rather than get the post, then get the meta, to try and just get both in one query.  As mentioned above it doesn't seem practical so going to skip it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Not worth it as it would be a convoluted query and work against most of the wp caching solutions.

Comment: This is not right nor an appropriate answer.

Comment: How do you figure?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single step, but it's easy to write & handle in code: [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) gives you **all** attached meta data. But be aware: Everything comes as array, even when it´s  a single value. So

```
// Ever entry comes like this.
// Example single value for 'Hair color':
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'Brown'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of code [source: WPSnipp.com](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/get-all-post-meta-data/)

Place this in your functions.php file...

```
function get_post_meta_all($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $data   =   array();
    $wpdb->query("
        SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value`
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE `post_id` = $post_id
    ");
    foreach($wpdb->last_result as $k => $v){
        $data[$v->meta_key] =   $v->meta_value;
    };
    return $data;
}
```

Or using get_post_custom() you can do this;

Place this in your functions.php file...

```
if ( !function_exists('base_get_all_custom_fields') ) {
    function base_get_all_custom_fields()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $hidden_field = '_';
        foreach( $custom_fields as $key => $value ){
            if( !empty($value) ) {
                $pos = strpos($key, $hidden_field);
                if( $pos !== false && $pos == 0 ) {
                    unset($custom_fields[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $custom_fields;
    }
}
```

Then within your theme files you can do the following;

```
$custom_fields = base_get_all_custom_fields();
if( !empty($custom_fields) ) {
    print_r($custom_fields);
}
```

Source [HERE](http://www.kevinleary.net/get-all-custom-fields-attached-post-page-post-type/)